# Javastatement in ps1 file is not executed as admin if mixed with other statements. (Error:Return argument has an invalid type)

Tags: java, powershell, batch-file, jenkins, hp-uft

context:

We try to configure runner vms for UFT and Selenium execution. These vms are citrix based and restart at night with the most up to date productive image and lose their automation configuration in this restartprocess.. Then a sheduled task executes a powershellscript with elevated rights which copies a jenkinsfolder to the vm, download the jenkins slave.jar for the connection, installs uft and eclipse and at last starts connection to jenkins.

1. If i start powershell as admin and execute the commands by hand everything works fine.
2. If i put it into a powershell scriptfile and execute it with a sheduled Task it looks all fine. But i get a "Return argument has an invalid type" in my job if i start a UFT testcase via jenkins. It looks like the connection is no started with elevated rights.
3. If i cut the script in half. All steps but the connection in one script and the connection in a second one, the testcase runs without any problems.

I rebuild the script in a batch file but is has the complete same behavior.

So option 3 is working but the citrix admins and my lead are not happy with such an unpredictable behavior. Does anyone has a hint how we can get the script running in one powershell script?

complete Scipt (produces the error):

```
switch -wildcard($env:computername){
    "wxp-guirun-p*" {

        robocopy '\\vhv\sachgebiete\Sachgebiete\Testautomatisierung\Installationsdateien\Runner\VhvEntw' 'c:\VHVEntw' /E

        Invoke-WebRequest https://jenkins-master.ads.vhv.de/jnlpJars/slave.jar -OutFile c:\vhvEntw\Jenkins\slave.jar

        cscript '\\vhv\sachgebiete\Sachgebiete\Testautomatisierung\Installationsdateien\Runner\UFT_3811-000\14.0\Package\Wrapper\Default\Wrapper_64.vbs'

        Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\HP.UFT.LicenseInstall.exe' -Argument 'concurrent 20402 1 SERVERADRESS'

        cscript '\\vhv\sachgebiete\Sachgebiete\Testautomatisierung\Installationsdateien\Runner\eclipse_1685-000\4.10.0\Package\Wrapper\Default\Wrapper.vbs'

        break;
       }

}

echo $env:computername

switch -wildcard($env:computername){

    "wxp-guirun-p01" {
           java -jar c:\vhventw\jenkins\slave.jar -jnlpUrl SERVERADRESS AND SECRET -workDir "C:\vhvEntw\Jenkins"
            break;
       }
}
```

Cut in half it works:

Installation:

```
switch -wildcard($env:computername){
    "wxp-guirun-p*" {

        robocopy '\\vhv\sachgebiete\Sachgebiete\Testautomatisierung\Installationsdateien\Runner\VhvEntw' 'c:\VHVEntw' /E

        Invoke-WebRequest https://jenkins-master.ads.vhv.de/jnlpJars/slave.jar -OutFile c:\vhvEntw\Jenkins\slave.jar

        cscript '\\vhv\sachgebiete\Sachgebiete\Testautomatisierung\Installationsdateien\Runner\UFT_3811-000\14.0\Package\Wrapper\Default\Wrapper_64.vbs'

        Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\HP.UFT.LicenseInstall.exe' -Argument 'concurrent 20402 1 SERVERADRESS'

        cscript '\\vhv\sachgebiete\Sachgebiete\Testautomatisierung\Installationsdateien\Runner\eclipse_1685-000\4.10.0\Package\Wrapper\Default\Wrapper.vbs'

        break;
       }

}
```

Connection:

```
echo $env:computername

switch -wildcard($env:computername){

    "wxp-guirun-p01" {
            java -jar c:\vhventw\jenkins\slave.jar -jnlpUrl SERVERADRESS AND SECRET -workDir "C:\vhvEntw\Jenkins"
            break;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your UFT.exe process is created using the Quicktest.Automation COM Object then the process will not inherit anything from it's parent process (like elevated rights, handlers, environment variables etc). It seems to be spinned of from the User Context.

As a Workaround you could start the UFT.exe process from the command Line (Disable Startup Screens and Add-In Selection), wait a bit and then connect to it with your Automation Object. In this way UFT will inherit your environment variables and handlers, and also the Elevated rights of the Parent Process (Jenkins)

Comment: Thx for your reply. We use the Microfocus Jenkins Plugin to start the testcase. If you say start UFT via cmd, do you mean start it on vm side or within the jenkins job (testrunner)? We will have a call with microfocus today. If we will not solve it in this session, i will try your workaround.

Comment: it has to be a batch step (bat keyword in the jenkins pipeline). Easiest is to write a batch file for it. If you use the Jenkins Plugin, this might not work, as the Jenkins Plugin may not like the fact that UFT.exe is already started, will close it, start it via COM and we are back to square 0. YOu would have to implement your own Automation of the UFT process.